# Problem involving a continuous map and Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the task of showing that if $f$ is continuous and $B$ is a Borel set, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel as well.

It is enough to show that the collection of sets whose preimage under $f$ is Borel is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains the open sets.

(notation: I am going to use $\mathbb{B}$ to denote the Borel sets)

Let $K = \{E \in \mathbb{R} : f^{-1}(E) \in \mathbb{B}\}$ be this collection.  I must prove that it is a $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. that it is closed under complements and countable unions, and thus by De Morgan's identities, also under countable intersections).

First for complements.  Let $E \in K$, then $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathbb{B}$.  Then $f^{-1}(E^c) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus E)$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Second for intersections.  Let $E_1, E_2, ...$ be a collection of sets in $K$.  Then $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}$E_k) should be a Borel set, however I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about doing it.

If I'm not mistaken, this is all that I have to show, as the countable intersections follow from the unions.

Is this the right path I should be taking or is there something better?

Comment: Don't forget that you also have to show that open sets are in $K$. But you're definitely on the right track! Here are some leading questions: of the statements $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$, $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$, $f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$, and $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$, three of them are always true and one is not; which ones? Do they generalize to infinite unions/intersections? Does this help you finish the proof?